# Explicit template specialization for constructor (g++)

Tags: c++, templates

I have this class definition in .h file:

```
class PolygonPath
{
  public:
    template<class T> explicit PolygonPath(const Polygon<T> &);
    template<class T> Polygon<T> toPolygon() const;
}
```

In .cpp file, I define my methods. Then, I would like to define explicit template for   `Polygon<float>` and `Polygon<long>`. So, I define them like that:

```
template class PolygonPath::PolygonPath<float>(const Polygon<float> &); //Fail
template class Polygon<float> PolygonPath::toPolygon<float>() const; //Ok
template class PolygonPath::PolygonPath<long>(const Polygon<long> &); //Fail
template class Polygon<long> PolygonPath::toPolygon<long>() const; //Ok
```

For constructor, I'm not able to define an explicit template specialization. I have this error at compilation: "**error: ‘PolygonPath’ is not a class template**".
I also try with this syntax:

```
template <> PolygonPath::PolygonPath(const Polygon<float> &)
```

It compiles but I get another error at link: "undefined reference to `urchin::PolygonPath::PolygonPath(urchin::Polygon const&)'".

Comment: You're saying "instantiate this class" and then naming a constructor, not a class.

Comment: `PolygonPath::PolygonPath` is not a class template. It's a function template. Why are you prepending the word class to it?

Answer (score 4):

Remove `class` from your constructor's explicit instantiation.

`template PolygonPath::PolygonPath<long>(const Polygon<long> &);`

and

`template Polygon<long> PolygonPath::toPolygon<long>() const;`